# Sqlite3 How to get number of rows in table without reading all the rows?

Tags: php, sql

Can some shed some light on hoe to get the number of rows (using php) in a table without actually having to read all the rows? I am using squlite to log data periodically and need to know the table row count before I actually access specific data?

Apart from reading all rows and incrementing a counter, I cannot seem to work out how to do this quickly (it's a large database) rather simple requirement? I have tried the following php code but it only returns a boolean response rather that the actual number of rows?

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM mdata');
```

Normally the SELECT statement will also return the data object (if there is any?)

Comment: query calls return a result HANDLE. You still have to actually FETCH a row to read the field(s) selected in the query. `$result = query(...); $row = fetch($result); echo $row['field'];` is the standard basic order-of-operations.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
LIMIT 1
```

That should work!! It Limits the result to ONLY look at 1 row!!

Answer (score 0):

if you have record set then you get number or record by mysql_num_rows(#Record Set#);

Comment: This question is not about Mysql but Sqlite.